# Remove quotes from a character object in R

Tags: r, quotes

Suppose you have a character object of the form
`"c('r1', 'r2', 'r3')"`

how can you strip the external quote marks to return `c('r1', 'r2', 'r3')`

Comment: But what do you want to return? another character value? I mean, if you `cat()` that first value, it won't have surrounding quotes because those are only there when character values are formatted for the console. Are you trying to treat a string like code?

Comment: I don't think I explained myself properly. I want to use the list as code in a `for` loop. but it keeps reading it as a string. please let me know if this clarification helps. thanks.

Comment: Basically you have R code in a string. If you want to run it get a vector out, you can use `eval(parse(text=))` though that can potentially be dangerous if you don't know what's in the string you are evaluating.

Comment: A question: how are you getting that in a string? There are some R expressions that will return a string-representation of an R object (such as what you have there); getting to that point means the code you intended to do something useful did not, instead munging the data. Perhaps if you share how you are retrieving a string like that, it's possible that what you're asking here will not be necessary.

Comment: This is [X-Y Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You have a problem `X` and you think removing the quotes is the solution to the problem (`Y`). You are explaining us all about `Y` instead of describing what `X` you want to do. Please explain what is it that you are trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming s is as shown below and you want to iterate over three character strings:

```
s <- "c('r1', 'r2', 'r3')"

rr <- eval(parse(text = s)) ; rr
## [1] "r1" "r2" "r3"

for(r in rr) print(r)  # can use it in a for loop like this
## [1] "r1"
## [1] "r2"
## [1] "r3"
```

or if what you meant is that r1, r2 and r3 are R variables then using rr from above:

```
r1 <- 1; r2 <- 2; r3 <- 3
L <- mget(rr)  # list with elements 1, 2 and 3
for(r in L) print(r)
## [1] 1
## [1] 2
## [1] 3
```

There may be some earlier step you can take to create an object easier to deal with in the first place but that can't be determined from the question as stated.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I ran into this issue because I performed a task for my research in python not R and needed to unite it with the main code hence how i ran into my problem. I apologize for not knowing how to explain it better.